# What data should i save in the Sqlite Database from my app?

Tags: android, sqlite

Okay, in my app I can add custom markers with images taken from the camera intent, then that image is then displayed full screen when the user taps on the marker.  Now for each marker added i had to use :

```
private Map<String, Bitmap> myMarkers;
```

then I needed to get the ID of the marker :

```
private String markerId;
....
markerId = marker.getId();
```

Then return that image to that specific marker:

```
Bitmap bitmap = myMarkers.get(marker.getId());
markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

All good and working,  now my question is what do i need to save to SQlite database? 
Is it the  `myMarkers` , the `markerID` or the `bitmap` or the `imageData` (seen in code below)?

```
 baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
 imageData = baos.toByteArray();
```

Or do I need to save all of them to the database?

Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a column with imageData(Blob) and tag it to your markerid(Primary key). so that it is easy to get retrieve from the DB.

Comment: thanks for your response,  so basically what i need to do is : `contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE, markerId);` and the retrieving : ` byte [] img = null; .... img = arg1.getBlob(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE));` ?

Comment: and then add that to my imageview

Comment: cool i can see it is saving the marker id to the database!!! :-) but (sorry for stupid question) but how do i then add that to my imageview?